# Initialise a new VARIANT from a void* pointer + a datatype

Tags: vba, casting, com, variant, ole-automation

I am using these two functions to read a value from a multidimensional safearray

```
Private Declare Sub SafeArrayGetElement Lib "OleAut32.dll" ( _
                    ByVal pSafeArray As LongPtr, _
                    ByRef rgIndices As Long, _
                    ByRef dataBuffer As Any)

Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetElemsize Lib "OleAut32.dll" (ByVal pSafeArray As LongPtr) As Long
```

- [`SafeArrayGetElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraygetelement)
- [`SafeArrayGetElemsize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraygetelemsize)

This is an example of how I use them:

```
Dim arr(1 to 2, 1 to 4) As Long 'or Integer, String, Object etc. Any datatype

Dim indices() As Long
ReDim indices(1 to CountOfDimensons(arr)) 'here arr is a 2D array so there are two indices
indices(1) = 1
indices(2) = 3

Dim resultBuffer() As Byte 'somewhere to read the data from the array into, big enough to hold whatever that is
ReDim resultBuffer(1 to SafeArrayGetElemsize(ArrPtr(arr)))

SafeArrayGetElement ArrPtr(arr), indices(1), resultBuffer(1) 'equivalent to resultBuffer = arr(1,3)
```

Now I have a resultBuffer with some data, and I can use `VarType(arr) xor vbArray` to get the vartype of the data. It could be Long, Integer, Variant etc...

How can I use those two pieces of information to create a variant? My idea was to have a big select case statement on the varType, declare variables of each type. Then use memcopy to hydrate those variables. Then assign their values to a new variant. However this is very over complicated. There must be an easier way to initialise a variant from some data.

Basically cast the `void*` to a `long*` or `variant*` etc. and then copy that into a Variant?

Comment: Why do you use interop at all? It will be easier to do all this including safe array management in VBA with CVar which has no counterpart in native code AFAIK. Automation types were invented for VB. Otherwise there's no magic and it's simple for simple type but complex for VT_ARRAY, VT_VECTOR, VT_BYREF, etc. For complex types you can use the InitVariantFromXXXX functions from propsys.dll (for ex: InitVariantFromDoubleArray) but you can't use functions like InitVariantFromInt32 because it's a pure C++ code thing from propvarutil.h, not an export.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm using this approach because I'm making a general purpose function which returns the `ith` element from a multidimensional array (as if I'd put it through a `for each elem in arr` loop `i` times, just in constant time with a direct index). I don't believe there is a way to do this in native VBA, so I have to use the helper array functions which in turn mean I have to do this low level casting in the question.

Comment: @Greedo I suppose you are not interested in the [NDArrayTo1DArray](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-ArrayTools/blob/master/src/LibArrayTools.bas#L1554) function as that needs to loop the entire array first. Am I correct?

Comment: Not sure what you can't do from VBA that would be easier by native code here.

Comment: @CristianBuse Yeah I had a look but I don't want to eagerly evaluate

Comment: @SimonMourier IIRC the variant struct actually stores the data in its native representation, so I can probably just copy the bytes into an empty variant and set its VT flag manually. I guess that's what you described in your 1st comment. Then I only need to select-case on the handful of more complex types.

Comment: What the VARIANT structure stores can be very complex and can contain a full hierarchy of things. VB Manipulates natively variants through its numerous internal functions. CVar has no equivalent in exported native code and will do the same as "copy the bytes into an empty variant and set its VT flag manually" (which again is far from sufficient for complex variants) plus more.

Comment: @SimonMourier That is fair I see your point about the hidden complexity. However `CVar` of course requires as input a VBA variable of a certain type, so now how do I get that variable of the correct type without something like reflection: `Dim elem As VarType(arr)`. I hope I've been able to explain my usecase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73602609/get-element-from-multidimensional-array-with-unknown-dimensions and why I feel I need this ability to cast a `void*` clearly?

Comment: @Greedo Just responded to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73619142/8488913) question. Maybe you don't need the ```SafeArrayGetElement``` API after all

Comment: Ok, I see the point (you're clearly using vb for things it wasn't made for). It would be easier if you could restrict to array of VARIANTs but otherwise if you can't get a vb thing usable in vb, you will have to go the switch way. Even for this switch, if you can restrict to support for simple integral types (no array of array, vectors, objects, etc.), it will be easier.